# Self Signed Certificate Windows Emulator - node.js application

Tags: windows, node.js, azure

Hello I'd like to do https calls from my node.js website running under windows azure emulator but I am not sure how to go about enabling ssl using IIS Express ?

Has anybody got any ideas? I've read and tried implementing different ideas but none seem to work for e.g.

https://tootallnate.net/setting-up-free-ssl-on-your-node-server

I am creating a Facebook app which requires me to do some https calls to the graph etc, but IIS Express crashes each time if it encounters warning messages etc and the call never makes it through.

Anyone got a simple self-signed certificate working within emulator that they can share on how they did it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between making outgoing calls using SSL from your service (for example, using facebook) versus accepting incoming ssl calls (for example, from the browser).  If you're making outgoing calls, standard node libraries should work and you'll just need a .pem certificate included in your app to use most of them.  If you're accepting https calls on the server, then iis (express) takes care of certificates and your server can treat the incoming call as http